# Connecting OpenOffice Calc/Spreadsheet files

Tags: sql-server, openoffice-calc

In order to query data that is listed into hundreds of OpenOffice Calc files, I'm currently using SQL Server (2014). As data can change, copying all data from the hundreds of Calc files is not an option.

Is there a way to setup connections within MS SQL Server or OpenOffice Base or MS Access to these Calc files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is more of a comment than an answer, I'm putting it here due to length.

OpenOffice Base is a front-end program that stores queries, forms, reports, and a connection to a back-end program.  The back-end program manages the tables, and Base can connect to any number of back-ends, including MS SQL Server, MS Access, and OpenOffice Calc.

A limitation in your situation is that one Base file can use as a back-end only one Calc file.  Could your data be exported to csv?  In that case Base could be set up to read each (of the hundreds) csv file in the same folder as one table in a database.

While each one Base file can connect to only one back-end, transfer between databases can be done by using another OpenOffice component (usually Writer or Calc) to connect to multiple Base files.  There is more information at [[Tutorial] Using registered datasources in Calc](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=18511) and [[Tutorial] Standalone Forms / Switchboard](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=40493).  Once the standalone form is set up a macro can be written to automatically copy data between databases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Lyri here: you can't use Calc as backend for SQL server (at least I'd be *very* surprised if you could, esp. reliably).

If you want to stick w/ the Calc files, one idea could be: create a 2nd sheet and store a checksum for each row in that sheet. only update those rows that don't match the checksum any more into SQL server...